# How to use switch between two store in one grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a two data set in which one i am loading in store. My grid is completely fine. Now in some certain condition i want to load 2nd data to my store. I am using extjs 3

My code for grid is :

```
{
xtype: 'grid',
id: 'COGRID,
autoHeight: true,
sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect:true}),
frame: true,
columns : this.columns,
store :  store, // store is loading my data.
stripeRows: true,
}
```

My store and data :

```
var myData = [       
['FFPE Slide',2,'eSample'],
['Plasma',2,'eSample'],
['Whole ',2,'eSample']  ];   
var myData2 = [       
['USA','at','a'],
['France','bt',b'],
['Aus','ct','c']  ]; 

 var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
fields: [
   {name: 'stype'},
   {name: 'scnt'},
   {name: 'src'}
 ]
 }); 
 store.loadData(myData);  // Here I am loading first data to store
```

Comment: What is your condition? You can set the second data in similar manner.

Comment: I have a button and when click on button I want to myData else my Data1

Answer (score 0):

button handler config , you need to set your data according to your requirement.

e.g

```
{
xtype:button,
text:'Click Me',
handler:function(btn){
    Ext.getCmp('COGRID').getStore().loadData(myData);
}
```